# All bridges have failed to connect TOR

Tags: error

I have tried all provided bridges namely
fte
meek amazon
meek azure
obfs 3/4
scramblesuit

Error is

I tried custom bridges via "get command" email to TOR but those also failed to connect.

Error is 
Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.

Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done - 88.140.128.43:443).

09-11-2016 21.14.36 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

09-11-2016 21.14.36 PM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

09-11-2016 21.14.43 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server

09-11-2016 21.14.43 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server

09-11-2016 21.14.43 PM.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.43 PM.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.43 PM.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50000 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.43 PM.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:2934 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.43 PM.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.43 PM.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:2413 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.43 PM.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:4319 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.43 PM.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.44 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50000 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.44 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.44 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.44 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:2413 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.44 PM.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:2934 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.44 PM.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.44 PM.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:4319 ("general SOCKS server failure")

09-11-2016 21.14.49 PM.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

09-11-2016 21.14.49 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

09-11-2016 21.14.49 PM.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

09-11-2016 21.14.50 PM.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

09-11-2016 21.16.54 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

09-11-2016 21.16.54 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

09-11-2016 21.16.54 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

09-11-2016 21.16.54 PM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

09-11-2016 21.17.10 PM.500 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 3; recommendation warn; host 578166B6AEF1C162602DC623A7DDE09E39B84859 at 88.140.128.43:443)

09-11-2016 21.17.10 PM.500 [WARN] 21 connections have failed:

09-11-2016 21.17.10 PM.500 [WARN]  18 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object)

09-11-2016 21.17.10 PM.500 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE

09-11-2016 21.17.10 PM.500 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN

09-11-2016 21.17.45 PM.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

09-11-2016 21.17.45 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

09-11-2016 21.17.45 PM.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

Burried under cyberoam

Comment: can you please post your torrc configs you used for pluggable transports and direct connection attempts? it will help us to clarify your problem

Comment: Can you visit the fronts for meek amazon and azure normally with a browser or do you get SSL errors or failed connection? e.g. https://a0.awsstatic.com or https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com